# How to build a project using Cargo in an offline environment?

Tags: linux, macos, rust

I have a laptop with an OS X system which can access the internet, and a Linux server which can not access internet for some security reason.

I want to build a Rust project with some dependency on the Linux server. Because the Linux server can not access internet, I run the `cargo build` command on the OSX laptop and download the dependency source file to the `.cargo` directory and then copy these files to the Linux server and put them into `/root/.cargo` directory.

I made the file structures the same, but when I run `cargo build` on the Linux server, it still tries to connect to [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index) website and the build fails. The `cargo build` command always tries to connect internet although the dep source files are already in the `.cargo` directory.

How can I build a Rust project with dependencies in an offline environment? Why does copying the source file of the dependencies not work?

Answer (score 24):

As of Rust 1.37, Cargo's built-in [`vendor` command](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/08/15/Rust-1.37.0.html#built-in-cargo-support-for-vendored-dependencies) can be used to download and bundle your crate's dependencies in the crate itself:

1. First, run `cargo vendor`. This will set up a new directory named `vendor` in the root of your crate. It will then download all required dependencies and store them in this new directory.
2. After `cargo vendor` is done downloading the dependencies, it will print a set of instructions that you need to follow. Currently, these instructions tell you to copy a few lines to `.cargo/config.toml`. Note that `config.toml` is relative to the root of your crate and is not the one in your home directory.

If you did both steps, your crate will be completely self-contained with respect to its dependencies. You can couple this approach with Rust's [offline installers](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html#standalone-installers) to build Rust programs completely offline.

Answer (score 5):

**For Rust 1.37+ see:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/65254702/147192

---

The short answer is: up to 1.37 (excluded), it's complicated.

The long answer is that `cargo` will attempt to connect to `github` in order to check the index of the crates that the `Cargo.toml` file references.

I recommend you to check the [cargo-vendor](https://github.com/alexcrichton/cargo-vendor) prototype to solve this issue (by aturon, a member of the Rust tooling subteam), and otherwise you could look at how some people [created a mirror](https://gmjosack.github.io/posts/dissecting-cratesio-minimum-mirror/) for crates.io in order to avoid the dependency on Internet.

There is a demand for Rust builds not to require Internet, and people working on it, however there is no blessed solution for now.

Comment: Beat me by *7 seconds*.  :P  Should also add that the asker's actual issue is that the *index* is kept in a GitHub repo; just mirroring the packages themselves isn't sufficient.

Comment: @DK.: isn't that already contained in my second paragraph? If you think it's not obvious enough I welcome any edit to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks very much. right now,it's really complicated~~~

Comment: @MatthieuM. Well, you mention `crates.io`, but that's just where the actual package files are stored, not the index.  So even mirroring *all* of `crates.io` isn't going to be sufficient.

Comment: This answer is outdated: Cargo can vendor external dependencies on its own without installing any additional tooling as early as Rust 1.37. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65254702/10126273) for more details.

Comment: @TendersMcChiken Thanks; I added the "redirection" notice, now we just your answer to be upvoted so it bubbles up, or for the OP to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [`romt` - Rust Offline Mirror Tool](https://github.com/drmikehenry/romt).

Romt (Rust Offline Mirror Tool) aids in using the Rust programming language in an offline context. Instructions and tooling are provided for:

- Mirroring of Rust ecosystem artifacts:

  - Toolchains (Rustc, Cargo, libraries, etc.)
  - Rustup (toolchain multiplexer)
  - Crates.io (community-supplied Crates)
- Incremental artifact downloading.
- Incremental artifact transfer to offline network.
- Artifact serving in offline context (offline computer, disconnected network).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up an offline cargo registry using panamax https://github.com/panamax-rs/panamax
The procedure is straight forward and well documented. The biggest advantage is you can setup a registry that contains only crates used in your project (that is good for build reproducibility). Also, then you can use your build procedure/scripts just like you are online.

Answer (score 0):

I could replace official crates.io registry use by adding this
.cargo/config file in my project (under windows %USERPROFILE%\.cargo\config seems ignored) :

```
[source]

[source.mirror]
registry = "http://localhost:8185/auser/crates.io-index.git"

[source.crates-io]
replace-with = "mirror"
```

Also works using a file based git registry clone:

```
registry = "file://c:/github/crates.io-index.git"
```

downloaded either using git clone --bare or --mirror

cargo build now print
`Updating 'c:\github\crates.io-index.git' index`
instead of `Updating crates.io index`

Answer (score 0):

Use the --offline arg:

```
cargo build --offline
```

Source: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-can-i-build-my-application-using-cargo-while-offline-without-internet/7021/5