# How do I use Cargo to build a project while offline?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am practicing rust (1.36) by creating small program using `rand` crate. but the problem is whenever i create new project using `cargo new` and then add `rand` dependency in `cargo.toml`. it connects to internet and download same `rand` package again.

In contrast to Python, installed packages go to site_package folder and become available for import/use to any program. Don't required to download again.

My question is, how do I tell cargo to look for already installed local crate rather than downloading again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build a project using Cargo in an offline environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267233/how-to-build-a-project-using-cargo-in-an-offline-environment)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even in modern Python, one wouldn't just use the globally available `site_packages` directory and "pollute" the globally available packages, but one would use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) to maintain proper versioning per project -- similar to what `cargo` does.

With `cargo`, once all the packages downloaded and their versions specified explicitly in a project, one can pass the new
`--offline` flag while one compiles one's project, in which case `cargo` *runs without accessing the network*:

```sh
$ cargo build --offline
```

That being said, doing something of what you described is of course perfectly possible:

1. Create a directory, where your dependencies go:

   ```sh
   $ mkdir offline_resources
   $ cd offline_resources
   ```
2. Download the repository you need and build it (this is the last point where you need to use the network):

   ```sh
   $ git clone https://github.com/rust-random/rand.git
   $ cd rand
   $ cargo build
   ```
3. Create a new project:

   ```
   $ cd ../..
   $ cargo new use_offline
   $ cd use_offline
   ```
4. Edit `Cargo.toml`:

   ```
   [dependencies]
   rand = { path="../offline_resources/rand", version="0.7.0" }
   ```
5. Build your project:

   ```
   $ cargo build --offline
   ```
6. Follow the steps from 3 to 5 to create another project which will use the same `rand` dependency.

Comment: thanks for the first paragraph, i was not aware about the importance of isolated package. And following your steps i can do what i wanted to do. but at step 2, cargo build produced some error about locating `crates.io~index`. After searching about it i found that, removing ~/.cargo/registry will solve the problem. Thanks for your great answer. https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4245