# How use rust/cargo without internet access?

Tags: rust, offline, rust-cargo

I have two PC A and B, A has internet access, B has not.

On A, I create a test project, run 'cargo build' successfully, and I copy the whole project and cargo home folder to B.

When I run 'cargo build' on B, cargo will create a new folder(host+new hash) under registry/index folder, and try to download crates from internet again, but these crates already has been downloaded.

I also try option '--offline', but no effect.

How can I let cargo use my cargo home copied from A?

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267233/how-to-build-a-project-using-cargo-in-an-offline-environment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build a project using Cargo in an offline environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267233/how-to-build-a-project-using-cargo-in-an-offline-environment)